# The <a> buttons' onClick method don't response on the Electron project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

I want to create layout of electron app like to VS Code but when I created it, I cannot click the  buttons, the onClick method don't response:

[image]

you see the onClick trigger, it don't response:

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import React from 'react'

import "@vscode/codicons/dist/codicon.css";
import styles from "./header.module.css";


export type TitlebarProps = {
  showPanel: boolean;
  showPrimarySideBar: boolean;
  showSecondarySideBar: boolean;
  onShowPanelChanged: (visible: boolean) => void;
  onShowPrimarySideBarChanged: (visible: boolean) => void;
  onShowSecondarySidebarChanged: (visible: boolean) => void;
};

function header(
  {
    showPanel,
    showPrimarySideBar,
    showSecondarySideBar,
    onShowPanelChanged,
    onShowPrimarySideBarChanged,
    onShowSecondarySidebarChanged,
  }: TitlebarProps
) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.titlebar}>
       <div className={styles.layoutControls}>
        <ul className={styles.actionsContainer}>
          <li>
            <a
              className={classNames(
                "codicon",
                showPrimarySideBar
                  ? "codicon-layout-sidebar-left"
                  : "codicon-layout-sidebar-left-off",
                styles.actionLabel
              )}
              role="button"
              aria-label="Toggle Primary Side Bar (⌘B)"
              title=""
              tab-index="0"
              onClick={() => {
                console.log('mk')
                onShowPrimarySideBarChanged(!showPrimarySideBar)
              }}
            ></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              className={classNames(
                "codicon",
                showPanel ? "codicon-layout-panel" : "codicon-layout-panel-off",
                styles.actionLabel
              )}
              role="button"
              aria-label="Toggle Primary Side Bar (⌘B)"
              title=""
              tab-index="0"
              onClick={() => onShowPanelChanged(!showPanel)}
            ></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              className={classNames(
                "codicon",
                showSecondarySideBar
                  ? "codicon-layout-sidebar-right"
                  : "codicon-layout-sidebar-right-off",
                styles.actionLabel
              )}
              role="button"
              aria-label="Toggle Primary Panel (⌘.)"
              title=""
              tab-index="0"
              onClick={() =>
                onShowSecondarySidebarChanged(!showSecondarySideBar)
              }
            ></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              className={classNames(
                "codicon codicon-layout",
                styles.actionLabel
              )}
              role="button"
              aria-label="Toggle Secondary Side Bar"
              title=""
              tab-index="0"
              onClick= {
                () => { console.log(111) }
              }
            ></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default header
```

the full Electron project code is there:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pfcp43

I tried use below code to preventDefault event, but not lucky.

```
onClick={(e) => {
                //console.log(e)
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('mk')
                onShowPrimarySideBarChanged(!showPrimarySideBar)
              }}
```

I created a react demo with the key code, and it works fine:

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/clwpf6

so, the difference is the upper issue demo is an electron framework.

Comment: Code should be posted **here**, not on an external site.

Comment: I wasn't able to get your codesandbox project to load and run, it had an error. Try to make a "minimal reproduction" version -- the smallest version of your code that has this problem, using as few libraries and other files as possible.

Comment: I updated my post, it's an electron project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you used `-webkit-app-region: drag;` in header:

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 28px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

if you want to area to be clickable, you should set sub area to `-webkit-app-region: no-drag;` like below:

```
.layoutControls {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 8px;
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
```

then the sub content of .layoutControls can be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag default functionality is to open a url, you need to prevent/block that in order to make onClick work. So your onClick function should look like this:

```
 onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log('mk')
            onShowPrimarySideBarChanged(!showPrimarySideBar)
          }}
```

Btw you shouldn't be using anchor tag if you want onClick to work properly as anchor tag needs href which is also missing, it will cause issue with it's functionality and even the build.

Comment: Thanks your response, but it don't work too.

Comment: It should work, maybe there is something wrong with the code, please share your repo.

Comment: just check the sandbox url, that's the full code.